# Viewing statues that are already built

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Is there any way to see the description of a statue after it's in place?  I know how to "View" it from the "Loo<kbd>k</kbd> Around" menu when they're just sitting in my stockpile, but the same doesn't work after they've been placed (with <kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the <kbd>t</kbd> key to examine the 'contents' of the statue, which will show you what the statue is of.

Comment: While examining the statue using `t`, you can also press Enter and then `v` to view the description of the statue, which will show you  further details about it, such as who the statue is of (the amount of detail depends on the quality of the statue).